# React native navigation not working with TouchableOpacity onPress

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I create a NavigationService.js file to handle the navigations:

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params,
    })
  );
}

// add other navigation functions that you need and export them

export default {
  navigate,
  setTopLevelNavigator,
};
```

Then, I have a page called Users where I have a TouchableOpacity that should navigate to UserDetails.js page.
Users.js:

```
...
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    ...
    this.goToUserDetails = this.goToUserDetails.bind(this);
}

goToUserDetails() {
    console.log('Here');
    NavigationService.navigate('UserDetails');
}
...
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.goToUserDetails()}>
...
```

When I click on the onPress link, I can see in the log the text 'Here', but it never navigates to the UserDetails page.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get any error logs?

Comment: No errors. It just don't navigate

Comment: I found the problem. I had to add the 'UserDetails' to my createSwitchNavigator